# show admin notice on specific error message in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried with this code but it doesn't work I need that the notice is shown when required:

```
function admin_notice_error($message) {
    add_action( 'admin_notices', 
        function () use ($message) {
            $class = 'notice notice-error';
            $msg = __( $message );
            printf( '<div class="%1$s"><p>%2$s</p></div>', esc_attr( $class ), esc_html( $msg ) ); 
        } 
    );
}

if ($var == false)
     admin_notice_error("there is an error");
```

Comment: The function works as expected. Double check if `$var` is `false`.

Comment: Where have you put this code? Test by putting it in `functions.php` of your active theme.

Comment: updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this , hope this will help but not tested . put in function.php

```
$message = 'this is an error'; 
    add_action( 'admin_notices', 
        function () use ($message) {
            $class = 'notice notice-error';
            $msg = __( $message );
            printf( '<div class="%1$s"><p>%2$s</p></div>', esc_attr( $class ), esc_html( $msg ) ); 
        } 
    );
```

Comment: Updated the anwser

Comment: Now it works, but it is always visible. I need to show the message after a setting button is pressed.

Comment: The problem is that the code you posted doesn't work inside a function. I don't know why, it make sense.

Comment: The problem that it doesn't work inside function is because when you call function `admin_notice_error`, the `admin_notices` action has already been fired and hence no effect.

Comment: Try putting your function call in action like `init` and it should work fine.